# Problem with specific rows in a grid using an api in a blazor project

Tags: c#, api, blazor, dx-data-grid

I'm having an issue with specific rows in a DevExpress grid connecting to the API properly.

i believe the problem is with the API because some of the rows in the grid i can manipulation by ether deleting ore editing them. But others like stated above some of the rows are not able to be ether edited or deleted but all the new data created is also able to be manipulated. hoping some one has had this issue be for, i'm providing some code and the error message for you guys to look at.

The code for the Grid

```
@page "/FetchData"
@inject HttpClient Http

<h2>DevExpress Data Grid:</h2>
@if (customer == null)
{
<h1>thinking!?!?!?</h1>
}
else
{
    <DxDataGrid Data=@customer
                DataNavigationMode="@DataGridNavigationMode.VirtualScrolling"
                RowRemoving=@((dataItem) => OnRowRemoving(dataItem))
                RowUpdating=@((updatingDataItem, newValues) => OnRowUpdating(updatingDataItem, newValues))
                RowInserting=@((newValues) => OnRowInserting(newValues))>
        <DxDataGridCommandColumn Width="150px"></DxDataGridCommandColumn>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(Customer.CustomerId) Caption="ID"></DxDataGridColumn>
        <DxDataGridColumn field=@nameof(Customer.FirstName) Caption="FirstName"></DxDataGridColumn>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(Customer.LastName) Caption="LastName"></DxDataGridColumn>

    </DxDataGrid>

    <br />
    <br />

    <DxDataGrid Data=@customer
                PageSize=15
                RowRemoving=@((dataItem) => OnRowRemoving(dataItem))
                RowUpdating=@((updatingDataItem, newValues) => OnRowUpdating(updatingDataItem, newValues))
                RowInserting=@((newValues) => OnRowInserting(newValues))>
        <DxDataGridCommandColumn Width="150px"></DxDataGridCommandColumn>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(Customer.CustomerId) Caption="ID"></DxDataGridColumn>
        <DxDataGridColumn field=@nameof(Customer.FirstName) Caption="FirstName"></DxDataGridColumn>
        <DxDataGridColumn Field=@nameof(Customer.LastName) Caption="LastName"></DxDataGridColumn>

    </DxDataGrid>
}

@functions {

        Customer[] customer;
        Customer cust = new Customer();

    private const string APIServer = "http://Notrealapi.com/api/customers/";

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        customer = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Customer[]>("http://Notrealapi.com/api/customers/");
    }

    async void OnRowRemoving(Customer dataItem)
    {
        await Http.DeleteAsync("http://Notrealapi.com/api/customers/" + dataItem.CustomerId);
        customer = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Customer[]>("http://Notrealapi.com/api/customers/");
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    async void OnRowUpdating(Customer dataItem, Dictionary<string, object> newValue)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> tempNewValues = new Dictionary<string, object>(newValue);
        cust = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Customer>("http://Notrealapi.com/api/customers/" + dataItem.CustomerId);
        foreach (var field in tempNewValues.Keys)
        {
            switch (field)
            {
                case "ID":
                    dataItem.CustomerId = (int)tempNewValues[field];
                    break;
                case "FirstName":
                    dataItem.FirstName = (string)tempNewValues[field];
                    break;
                case "LastName":
                    dataItem.LastName = (string)tempNewValues[field];
                    break;
            }
        }
        //dataItem.FirstName = cust.FirstName;
        //dataItem.LastName = cust.LastName;
        await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Put, "http://Notrealapi.com/api/customers/" + dataItem.CustomerId, dataItem);
        cust = new Customer();
        customer = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Customer[]>("http://Notrealapi.com/api/customers/");
        StateHasChanged();
    }

    async void OnRowInserting(Dictionary<string, object> newValue)
    {
        Dictionary<string, object> tempNewValues = new Dictionary<string, object>(newValue);
        cust = new Customer();
        await Http.SendJsonAsync(HttpMethod.Post, "http://Notrealapi.com/api/customers/", tempNewValues);
        cust = new Customer();
        customer = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Customer[]>("http://Notrealapi.com/api/customers/");
        StateHasChanged();
    }


    public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

some code from the API
Customer.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace testsitegp.Models
{
    public partial class Customer
    {
        public Customer()
        {
            Order = new HashSet<Order>();
        }

        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zipcode { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Order> Order { get; set; }
    }
}
```

CustomerController.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Net;
using testsitegp.Models;
using testsitegp.contracts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors;

namespace HPlusSportsAPI.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Customers")]
    public class CustomersController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ICostomerRepository _customerRepository;

        public CustomersController(ICostomerRepository costomerRepository)
        {
            _customerRepository = costomerRepository;
        }

        private async Task<bool> CustomerExists(int id)
        {
            return await _customerRepository.Exists(id);

        }

        //[EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
        [HttpGet]
        [Produces(typeof(DbSet<Customer>))]
        public IActionResult GetCustomer()
        {
            var results = new ObjectResult(_customerRepository.GetAll())
            {
                StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK
            };

            Request.HttpContext.Response.Headers.Add("X-Total-Count", _customerRepository.GetAll().Count().ToString());

            return results;
        }

        //[EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        [Produces(typeof(Customer))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCustomer([FromRoute] int id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var customer = await _customerRepository.Find(id);

            if (customer == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(customer);
        }

        //[EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        [Produces(typeof(Customer))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PutCustomer([FromRoute] int id, [FromBody] Customer customer)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != customer.CustomerId)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            try
            {
                await _customerRepository.Update(customer);
                return Ok(customer);
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if(!await CustomerExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }              
            }
        }

        //[EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
        [HttpPost]
        [Produces(typeof(Customer))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> PostCustomer([FromBody] Customer customer)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            await _customerRepository.Add(customer);

            return CreatedAtAction("GetCustomer", new { id = customer.CustomerId }, customer);
        }

        //[EnableCors("AnotherPolicy")]
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        [Produces(typeof(Customer))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteCustomer([FromRoute] int id)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (! await CustomerExists(id))
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            await _customerRepository.Remove(id);

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

CustomerRepository.cs

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using testsitegp.contracts;
using testsitegp.Models;

namespace testsitegp.repository
{
    public class CustomerRepository : ICostomerRepository
    {
        private H_Plus_SportsContext _context;

        public CustomerRepository(H_Plus_SportsContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public async Task<Customer> Add(Customer customer)
        {
            await _context.Customer.AddAsync(customer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return customer;
        }

        public async Task<bool> Exists(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Customer.AnyAsync(c => c.CustomerId == id);
        }

        public async Task<Customer> Find(int id)
        {
            return await _context.Customer.Include(customer => customer.Order).SingleOrDefaultAsync(a => a.CustomerId == id);
        }

        public IEnumerable<Customer> GetAll()
        {
            return _context.Customer;
        }

        public async Task<Customer> Remove(int id)
        {
            var customer = await _context.Customer.SingleAsync(a => a.CustomerId == id);
            _context.Customer.Remove(customer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return customer;
        }

        public async Task<Customer> Update(Customer customer)
        {
            _context.Customer.Update(customer);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return customer;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the setup class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using testsitegp.Models;
using testsitegp.contracts;
using testsitegp.repository;
using H_Plus_Sports.Contracts;
using H_Plus_Sports.Repositories;

namespace testsitegp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddScoped<ICostomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IOrderItemRepository, OrderItemRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IOrderRepository, OrderRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
            services.AddScoped<ISalespersonRepository, SalespersonRepository>();

           // services.AddCors(options =>
           //{
                //options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
               // builder =>
                //{
                    //builder.WithOrigins("https://websitetestgp.azurewebsites.net", 
                        //"https://websitetest22.azurewebsites.net", 
                        //"https://websitetest23.azurewebsites.net",
                        //"http://goodtest.com",
                       // "http://localhost:57870")
                                        //.AllowAnyHeader()
                                        //.AllowAnyMethod();
               //});
               // options.AddPolicy("AnotherPolicy",
               // builder =>
                //{
                    //builder.WithOrigins("https://websitetestgp.azurewebsites.net", 
                        //"https://websitetest22.azurewebsites.net", 
                        //"https://websitetest23.azurewebsites.net",
                        //"http://goodtest.com",
                        //"http://localhost:57870")
                                        //.AllowAnyHeader()
                                        //.AllowAnyMethod();
              //  });
           // });

            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            var connection = "Server=tcp:testsitegp.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=H_Plus_Sports;Persist Security Info=False;" +
                "User ID=_____;Password=______;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;";

            services.AddDbContext<H_Plus_SportsContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            //app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error i get when i try to manipulation one of the broken rows

> blazor.server.js:15 [2019-08-01T12:48:22.608Z] Error: System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.. ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10054): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.GetResult(Int16 token)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.FillAsync()
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpConnection.ChunkedEncodingReadStream.CopyToAsyncCore(Stream destination, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.GetStringAsyncCore(Task`1 getTask)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.HttpClientJsonExtensions.GetJsonAsync[T](HttpClient httpClient, String requestUri)
>      at Websitewithpopup.Pages.BigGrid.OnRowUpdating(Customer dataItem, Dictionary`2 newValue) in Q:\testsite\WebsitewithpopupDemoHP\Websitewithpopup\Pages\BigGrid.razor:line 123
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.b__139_0(Object state)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.ExecuteSynchronously(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, SendOrPostCallback d, Object state)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.<>c.<.cctor>b__23_0(Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.RendererSynchronizationContext.ExecuteBackground(WorkItem item)
>
> [2019-08-01T12:48:22.610Z] Information: Connection disconnected.

Pic 1:

[grid first loaded:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwDpy.png)

Pic 2:

[grid after pressing edit on one of the broken data rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYCZk.png)

Pic 3:

[grid after pressing update in the edit box on a broken data rows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fugik.png)

Pic 4:

[grid after pressing edit on one of the working data rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3x2ds.png)

Pic 5:

[grid after pressing update in the edit box on a working data rows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Za9t5.png)

Comment: Better add a mention and a tag for where DxDataGrid comes from.

Comment: Good call, i added a tag. thanks

Comment: @gpjs, what does this code do?  protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        customer = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Customer[]>("http://Notrealapi.com/api/customers/");
    }
Does it populate the customer array and provide  the data to the grid? Where does your database is located ? Could you please show us your Startup class

Comment: The stack trace ponts to OnRowUpdating, GetJsonAsync. But you call that twice, so which line is 123 ?

Comment: Once again, Where does your database is located ? I want to know where your data come from... Is your database is located on the same server your Blazor app is executed? Or it comes from a call you make to a data service website, like sportsdata, for example. Could you please show us your Startup class

Comment: @Issac i have added the setup class above the error code

Comment: @HenkHolterman the line you are looking for is  "cust = await Http.GetJsonAsync<Customer>("http://Notrealapi.com/api/customers/" + dataItem.CustomerId);" it is located in the second line of the async void OnRowUpdating method, there is two calls to this method because there is to grids of the same data on the page.

Comment: Can you remove `Customer cust`  everywhere and build agin?  You don't seem to use it, the logic around it is doubtful.

Comment: i removed it in the OnRowInserting becaues your right it was not needed there. But it is needed in the OnRowUpdating, without it all the rows do not work.

Comment: About the pictures: why do you have 2 grids on that page?  The 'working' example does not appear in the 1st grid, is that the pattern?

Comment: Try it with 1 grid on a page first.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the first grid is the exact same as the second except with a scroll bar instead of a pager. the error occurs in both grids on the same rows.

Comment: it is the same with only one grid on the page

Comment: Sorry, @gpjs, can't help you with this.